# Need some guidance on creating a jEditable custom input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, jeditable

I'm using the jEditable plugin and the following code to toggle between On and Off for a series of settings on a page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.editable_select').editable(''http://someexamplepage.com/save.php', { 
    indicator: '<img src="/images/spinner.gif">',
    data   : " {'&#x2713;':'&#x2713;','&#x2717;':'&#x2717;'} ",
    tooltip : 'Click to Edit',
    type   : 'select',
    onblur : 'submit',
    style  : 'inherit'
    });
});
```

And then this in the html:

```
<b class="editable_select" id="setting1" style="display:inline">&#x2713;</b>
```

When the checkmark indicating On is clicked, it produces a dropdown menu with checkmark for On and the X for Off in it, which the user can then select. What I would prefer is that clicking the check/X not open a dropdown, but instead send the current On or Off setting to the save.php file. I could then just write the save.php file to return the opposite value, so that clicking just toggles between the two without opening any kind of edit window. I tried the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.editable_select').editable('http://someexamplepage.com/save.php', { 
    indicator: '<img src="/images/spinner.gif">',
    tooltip : 'Click to Edit',
    onclick : 'submit',
    style  : 'inherit'
});
```

});

But clicking the text still opens a little editing window, which I don't want. I'm still new to JavaScript and jQuery, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or provide a live example? But honestly, if you're just trying to record a click action on the back end, just write a listener for the click event for these buttons and wire it into an `$.ajax` call. No need to use a plugin.

Comment: [Here's a live example](http://jimjatho.com/test). I focus mainly on PHP and MySQL, so I have a very basic grasp on Javascript and jQuery, which is why I try to use pre-made plugins when possible.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a plugin for this, but rather a very simple bit of jQuery to run on the `ready` event.

I would include the current state as a data attribute on the DOM, so change your tags to:

```
<b class="editable_select" id="[ID FOR ITEM]" data-state="checked">&#2713;</b>
```

Then do something like:

```
$(function(){
    var update_dom = function(data){
        var item_id = data.id;
        var state;
        data.state === 'checked' ? state = '✓' : state = '✗';
        $('#'+item_id).data('state', data.state).html(state);
    };

    var selected = function(evt){
        var item_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var state = $(this).data('state');
        $.ajax({
            url: PATH_TO_SCRIPT, 
            data: {id: item_id, state: state},
            type: "POST",
            success: update_dom
        });
    }

    $('.editable_select').click(selected);
});
```

This binds the `click` event to everything that has a class of `editable_select`. When you click on it, it'll call the `selected` function, which wil get the data from the DOM, and call your script.  When your script is complete, it should send back a response (JSON would be good here), and, the `success` handler will update the DOM and display the state back to the user.

Comment: I appreciate that help, but being the javascript novice that I am, it's not 100% clear to me which parts are meant to be left as-is and which are placeholders. I started a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4nU7v/

Comment: It should be almost wholesale to go with just replacing PATH_TO_SCRIPT. This will catch a click event on your <b> element, send the current state to the backend, receive a new state object and set the visual display (and data attribute) to the value returned by the server.

Comment: I gotcha. I wasn't sure about the "update_dom" part; it looked like some kind of info should have been substituted by me since there were no quotes around it. Just to be clear, if I use PHP on the backend as the "PATH_TO_SCRIPT" then whatever I echo at the end is what will show up, right? That's the way I've had it working so far.

Comment: You're going to want to return a JSON document to the client.  So the output of the script should have a `Content-type: application/json` and the contents should be `{id: ITEM_ID, state: NEW_STATE}` with those two values being variable.